# Form validation, required inputs, JS, trying to combine these two functions

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to combine these two functions:

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["form1"]["condition1"].value;
        var y = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"].value;
        var z = document.forms["form1"]["condition3"].value;

        if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a 'condition1' value");
        return false;
        }

        if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Please enter a 'condition2' value");
        return false;
        }
        if (z == null || z == "") {
        alert("Please enter a 'condition3' value");
        return false;
        }
    }

// Form Validation for pages with no 'condition2' option

    function validateForm2() {
        var x = document.forms["form1"]["condition1"].value;
        var z = document.forms["form1"]["condition3"].value;

        if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a 'condition1' value");
        return false;
        }
        if (z == null || z == "") {
        alert("Please enter a 'condition3' value");
        return false;
        }
    }
```

validateForm() checks to see if condition1, condition2, and condition3 were successfully inputted into Form1 and alerts user if not.

Some pages that use Form1 do not have a condition2.

As it stands a page that does not have a 'condition2' input will not work. A pretty easy workaround was to just make an almost identical function validateForm2() where 'condition2' is omitted. I then have to go through and sort which pages need which function.

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

or

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm2()">
```

I'm trying to see if i can combine the two functions by making 'condition2' only required when its actually on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one validateForm function

```
function validateForm() {
    var isPresentCond2 = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"],
        x = document.forms["form1"]["condition1"].value,
        y,
        z = document.forms["form1"]["condition3"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please enter a 'condition1' value");
    return false;
    }
    if (isPresentCond2) {
        y = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"].value;
        if (y == null || y == "") {
            alert("Please enter a 'condition2' value");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (z == null || z == "") {
    alert("Please enter a 'condition3' value");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think the "if (isPresentCond2)" part of the statement checks to see if condition2 exists.  I could be wrong, but again i really appreciate the help.

Comment: isPresentCond2 = document.forms["form1"]["condition2"] is testing for the presence of an input named "condition2" inside a form named "form1". If is not present it returns undefined which in a conditional is equal to false. null, "" and undefined are all falsy values in javascript.

Comment: You could also replace if (z == null || z == "") for if (z) and so on. Works the same way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now the concept is clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

In your javascript

```
 function validate()
 {
   if(required_condition_both)
    {
      return  validateForm();

    }
   else if(required_condition1_only)
    {  
      return  validateForm2();
    }


 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that is a much better workaround.  devconcept came up with a single function to cover everything.  Thanks again for your help/time.